# Parse array and turn values into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have an array that I need to turn into an object with the given values.

This is the input array

```
let actions = ['CREATE: id=14&amount=800&currency=USD','FINALIZE: id=14&amount=800&currency=USD','PAY: id=14' 
]
```

How would I turn it into this object.

```
let result ={
 'create': 800,
 'finalize': 800,
 'pay':14
}
```

so far I have a loop to check if the key in the array is available, but I'm lost on next steps. One of coworkers say Regex might be the best option.

```
for(let x = 0; x <=actions.length;x++){
    if(actions[x].icludes('CREATE')){

    } else(actions[x].icludes('FINALIZE')){

    } else(actions[x].icludes('PAY')){

    }
}
```

Ant help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split each string at `:\s+` to get a key and the string to be parsed. You'll get 2 values in the resulting array. Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get them to separate variables

```
["CREATE", "id=14&amount=800&currency=USD"]
```

Then use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) constructor on the second value get a key-value pair from the query string.

Some keys need `amount` while some keys need `id`'s value. So, you can create a mapper object. This maps the key with the *name* to be searched inside URLSearchParams.

```
const mapper = {
  PAY: "id",
  CREATE: 'amount',
  FINALIZE: 'amount',
  default: "amount"
};
```

Here, `PAY` needs `id` value. If you have more keys, you could add it here. You could add `CREATE: "amount"` to this object as well. But, since that is the `default`, I have skipped that. The `default` key can be used if a key is not found in `mapper`. Return an object with the key and the value from the parse function.

Then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array and merge each parsed object to create the output

```js
const actions = ['CREATE: id=14&amount=800&currency=USD', 'FINALIZE: id=14&amount=800&currency=USD', 'PAY: id=14']

const mapper = {
  PAY: "id",
  //CREATE: 'amount', // you could add CREATE and FINALIZE if you want
  default: "amount"
};

function parse(str) {
  const [key, value] = str.split(/:\s+/);
  const param = new URLSearchParams(value).get(mapper[key] || mapper.default);
  return { [key.toLowerCase()]: param };
}

const output = actions.reduce((acc, str) => Object.assign(acc, parse(str)), {});

console.log(output)
```

Comment: gorgeous approach

Comment: I actually like like this approach, thank you and it your explanation was very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your expected output doesn't follow a single structure, i opted for returning all values, instead of an arbitrary one. How ever if you have some business logic to justify selecting different values to return, you could easily change the code to accommodate this.

```js
const actions = [
  'CREATE: id=14&amount=800&currency=USD',
  'FINALIZE: id=14&amount=800&currency=USD',
  'PAY: id=14' 
];

const actionsData = actions.reduce((res, str) => {
  const [op, query] = str.split(': '); 
  
  const kvPairs = query.split('&');
  
  const data = kvPairs.reduce((res, kvStr) => {
    const [key, value] = kvStr.split('=');
    res[key] = value;
    return res;
  }, {});
  
  res[op] = data;
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(actionsData);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a regex example, this could also work. Of course, there may be a more robust regex rule always. (and more scalable)

```
let actions = [
  'CREATE: id=14&amount=800&currency=USD',
  'FINALIZE: id=14&amount=800&currency=USD',
  'PAY: id=14' 
]

let result = actions.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (item.match(/^CREATE:.+amount=(\d+)/)) {
    acc.create = item.match(/^CREATE:.+amount=(\d+)/)[1];
  } else if (item.match(/^FINALIZE:.+amount=(\d+)/)) {
    acc.finalize = item.match(/^FINALIZE:.+amount=(\d+)/)[1];
  } else if (item.match(/^PAY:.+id=(\d+)/)) {
    acc.id = item.match(/^PAY:.+id=(\d+)/)[1];
  };
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
let actions = ['CREATE: id=14&amount=800&currency=USD','FINALIZE: id=14&amount=800&    currency=USD','PAY: id=14']
let actionObject = [];

for(let i=0;i<actions.length;i++){

    // Split where it has colon and space
    let splitter = actions[i].split(": ");

    // Get label (and make it lowercase)
    let theLabel = splitter[0].toLowerCase();

    // remove label from array
    splitter.splice(0,1);

    // rejoin array if any values contained colon and space
    splitter = splitter.join(": ");

    // find amount= and split that
    splitter2 = splitter.split("amount=");

    // splitter2[1] will be everything after "amount="
    // if amount= didn't exist it will be undefined
    if(splitter2[1] !== undefined){
        // Now we just split the other side of the amount where &
        // if amount is the last thing and there's no &, it won't matter
        splitter2 = splitter2[1].split("&");

        // Now create the key (l1) and value (splitter2[0])
        actionObject[l1] = splitter2[0];
    }else{
        // If amount is not found, we get id instead, same process
        splitter2 = splitter.split("id=");
        if(splitter2[1] !== undefined){
            splitter2 = splitter2[1].split("&");
            actionObject[l1] = splitter2[0];
        }
    }
}
```

So, now you have an object, actionObject and it contains the amounts, but only for the values that contained amount or id.

```
actionObject {
    create: "800",
    finalize: "800",
    pay: "14"
}
```